# how to make substring in apache header

Tags: apache, header, substring

I've an apache 2.4 on a redhat server and I create an http-header in the httpd.conf with this directive:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [E=X_REMOTE_USER:%1]
    RequestHeader set SM_USER %{X_REMOTE_USER}e
```

the **SM_USER** header is correctly created but is with domain (utente@domain.com).
I would like to remove the @domain.com using a sort of substring (even creating another header). which syntax I should to use?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution using the regular expression:

```
RequestHeader set SM_USER %{X_REMOTE_USER}e 
RequestHeader edit SM_USER (?=@)(\S+)
```